# Is the Borel sigma algebra complete under some measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets, borel-measures

A measure space $(X,F,\mu)$ is complete if whenever $\mu(E)=0$, every subset of $E$ is an element of $F$.  Every incomplete measure space has a *completion*, which extends the sigma algebra to more sets and extends the measure to those sets. Most famously, the Borel algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ is incomplete with respect to Lebesgue measure, but it can be extended to a bigger sigma algebra, the Lebesgue signma algebra, which is complete with respect to Lebesgue measure.

But question is, does there exist a measure under which the Borel sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ is complete?  Or is it incomplete under every measure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Borel $\sigma$-algebra on any space is complete with respect to counting measure, since the only null set for counting measure is the empty set.

However, the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ is not complete with respect to any $\sigma$-finite measure.  Note that $\mathbb{R}$ is Borel-isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ (see [Are the measurable spaces $(\mathbb{R}^n, Bor(\mathbb{R}^n))$ and $(\mathbb{R}^m, Bor(\mathbb{R}^m))$ isomorphic for $n\neq m$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2465128/are-the-measurable-spaces-mathbbrn-bor-mathbbrn-and-mathbbrm), for instance), so let us work with $\mathbb{R}^2$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$.  So suppose $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Note then the sets $\mathbb{R}\times\{t\}$ as $t$ ranges over $\mathbb{R}$ are disjoint, and so by $\sigma$-finiteness of $\mu$ we must have $\mu(\mathbb{R}\times\{t\})=0$ for all but countably many $t\in\mathbb{R}$.  Since not every subset of $\mathbb{R}\times\{t\}$ is Borel, this measure space is not complete.

Comment: Nice answer @Wofsey .